# My app is rejected with Exception EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I tested my app on iPhone and iPad devices and it works fine, also I tested it on iOS 10.1.1 and on IPV6 network and it also works fine but after uploading my app to the app store, it is rejected because it crashes when login if the device is offline or on Wifi. They gave me a crash report  and after I symplocited it, I get thhis Info :

```
Date/Time:           2016-11-01 10:07:03.2150 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-11-01 10:05:21.7124 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1 (14B72)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000f18c0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       -[FIRMessagingSecureSocket closeStream:] (in MyApp) + 56
1   MyApp                       -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore openDatabase:] (in MyApp) + 228
2   MyApp                       -[FIRMessagingReceiver didSendDataMessageWithID:] (in MyApp) + 128
3   Foundation                      0x00000001835e08f8 
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aa48f4 
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aa4608 
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aa3ec4 
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aa1ac0 
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001829d0048 
9   GraphicsServices                0x0000000184456198 
10  UIKit                           0x00000001889b42fc 
11  UIKit                           0x00000001889af034 
12  MyApp                       -[FIRMessagingClient tryToConnect] (in MyApp) + 212 
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001819b45b8
```

**update**  : 
  I published new version put also get this crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000a1658
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       [FIRAMeasurement setUserAttributeOnWorkerQueue:]      (in MyApp) + 580
1   MyApp                       [FIRAMeasurement uploadData] (MyApp) + 180 0x100054000 + 303808
2   MyApp                       [FIRAMeasurement reportOSUpdateOnWorkerQueue] (in PetCasa Vet) + 124
3   Foundation                      0x0000000187acc8f8 0x1879c1000 + 1095928
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f908f4 0x186eb3000 + 907508
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f90608 0x186eb3000 + 906760
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f8fec4 0x186eb3000 + 904900
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f8dac0 0x186eb3000 + 895680
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186ebc048 0x186eb3000 + 36936
9   GraphicsServices                0x0000000188942198 0x188936000 + 49560
10  UIKit                           0x000000018cea02fc 0x18ce25000 + 504572
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ce9b034 0x18ce25000 + 483380
12  MyApp                       0x00000001000907d8 (in MyApp) + 448
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185ea05b8 0x185e9c000 + 17848
```

and this log crash :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000e5658
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                   0x00000001000e5658 (in MyApp) + 1060
1   MyApp                       [FIRMessagingConnection  loginRequestWithToken:authID:] (in MyApp) + 300
2   MyApp                       [FIRMessagingConnection initWithAuthID:token:host:port:runLoop:rmq2Manager:gcmManager:] (in MyApp) + 32
3   Foundation                      0x0000000187acc8f8 0x1879c1000 + 1095928
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f908f4 0x186eb3000 + 907508
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f90608 0x186eb3000 + 906760
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f8fec4 0x186eb3000 + 904900
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f8dac0 0x186eb3000 + 895680
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186ebc048 0x186eb3000 + 36936
9   GraphicsServices                0x0000000188942198 0x188936000 + 49560
10  UIKit                           0x000000018cea02fc 0x18ce25000 + 504572
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ce9b034 0x18ce25000 + 483380
12  MyApp                       [FIRInstanceIDRegistrationClient parseToken:authToken:withRequestID:handler:] (in MyApp) + 564 
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185ea05b8 0x185e9c000 + 17848
```

Comment: Share your relevant code of appDelegate. Also try debugin your code at which exact line does your code crashes.

Comment: Hi @Dravidian  In my code i just use         FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                ////print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                ////print("Connected to FCM.")
            } and it work fine so i cannot find crash

Answer (score 12):

From apple documentation

> Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]
>
> ```
>  ......
>  ......
> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected
> condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>  1- a non-optional type with a nil 
>  2- value a failed forced type conversion
> ```

In my app I use location and I send it to backend, and it works fine, but when opening app at first time, system show alert to say that my app want to use your location allow or not allow, if user didn't allow so location methods will not work and location will be nil and unfortunately I didn't check if location is nil so when unwrap it app crashed, it's my mistake.

Comment: I know this is old but where did you get this information? I cannot find the trap codes.

Comment: @Juanjo, you will find it in crash file, but it will be there if your app crash because of above two reasons.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz go to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html and search about Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]

Answer (score 1):

Please send message to the Apple review team about same and ask to them 
"We tested application on iPhone 6, 6s, 7 and 7+ with iOS 10.x and application works perfect in IPV6 network, We follow following process for IPV6 network: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/" and request to them your event will be held on the coming week so, please release application to store asap and let me know the flow of the application, where you find issue or crashes.

It works, I had done same thing with 4 application and they approved.

Comment: Hi Sandeep I will do that you suggest and I will tell you result , thanks.

Comment: Hi @Hosny: Did you found any solution or is there an any issue with code?. I have same issue and apple has rejected my app with Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP).

Comment: Hi @MehulSojitra , yes I put my answer for my question please read it .